# C++ variadic template partial specialization for non-type arguments

Tags: c++, c++11, tuples, variadic-templates

I have a `map_n` template that applies an N-arity function to each set of elements from N input tuples to produce a new output tuple. All input tuples must be of same length (which I should probably check with static assert).

The code works correctly, except I have not been able to write the recursion termination condition partial specialization in a generic way as shown in the following code snippet.

```
#include <tuple>
#include <cassert>

namespace impl {
    // car, cdr, cons implementation 
    // 
    template<unsigned... XS>
    struct sequence {
        template<unsigned X>
        using cons = sequence<X, XS...>;
    };

    template<unsigned start, unsigned end>
    struct range {
        static_assert(start < end, "Range: start > end");
        using type = typename range<start + 1, end>::type::template cons<start>;
    };

    template<unsigned start>
    struct range<start, start> {
        using type = sequence<>;
    };

    template<typename T, unsigned... N>
    auto select(const T& t, sequence<N...>) {
        return std::make_tuple(std::get<N>(t)...);
    }

} // end namespace impl

// car, cdr, cons 
// 
// empty list 
// 
constexpr const std::tuple<> empty;

// car 
// 
template<typename T>
auto car(const T& t) { return std::get<0>(t); }

// cdr 
// 
template<typename T, typename R = typename impl::range<1, std::tuple_size<T>::value>::type>
auto cdr(const T& t) {
    return impl::select(t, R());
}

// cons 
// 
template<typename X, typename... XS>
auto cons(X x, const std::tuple<XS...>& t) {
    return std::tuple_cat(std::make_tuple(x), t);
}

namespace impl {
    // map_n implementation 
    template<typename F, typename... Ts>
    struct map_n_impl {
        static auto map(const F& f, const Ts&... t) {
            return cons(
                f(car(t)...), 
                map_n_impl<F, decltype(cdr(t))...>::map(f, cdr(t)...)
                );
            }
        };

    // NOTE: Need a more general specialization here 
    // 
    template<typename F>
    struct map_n_impl<F, std::tuple<>, std::tuple<>> {
        static std::tuple<> map(const F&, const std::tuple<>&, const std::tuple<>&)
        {
            return std::make_tuple();
        }
    }; 
} // end namespace impl

// map_n 
// 
template<typename F, typename... Ts>
auto map_n(const F& f, const Ts&... t) {
    return impl::map_n_impl<F, Ts...>::map(f, t...);
}


int main(int, const char **) {
    {
        auto tup1 = std::make_tuple(1.0, 2.0, 3.0);
        auto tup2 = std::make_tuple(0.0, 1.0, 2.0);
        auto r = map_n([](auto x, auto y) { return x - y; }, tup1, tup2);
        assert(std::get<0>(r) == 1.0);
        assert(std::get<1>(r) == 1.0);
        assert(std::get<2>(r) == 1.0);
    }

    // {
    //  auto tup1 = std::make_tuple(1.0, 2.0, 3.0);
    //  auto tup2 = std::make_tuple(0.0, 1.0, 2.0);
    //  auto tup3 = std::make_tuple(4.0, 5.0, 6.0);
    //  auto r = map_n([](auto x, auto y, auto z) { return x - y + z; }, tup1, tup2, tupe3);
    //  assert(std::get<0>(r) == 5.0);
    //  assert(std::get<1>(r) == 6.0);
    //  assert(std::get<2>(r) == 7.0);
    // }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a lot easier than what you're going for. You don't need `map_n_impl` at all. If we're going to stick with the functional, recursive approach - we need two overloads of `map_n`: one for all the tuples are non-empty and one for all the tuples are empty. We'll use Columbo's `bool_pack` trick to figure out if they're all empty or not:

```
template <bool... >
struct bool_pack;

template <bool... b>
using all_true = std::is_same<bool_pack<true, b...>, bool_pack<b..., true>>;

template <class... T>
using all_empty = all_true<std::is_same<T, std::tuple<>>::value...>;
```

And then just use that to SFINAE the two disjoint conditions:

```
template<typename F, typename... Ts,
    std::enable_if_t<!all_empty<Ts...>::value, int*> = nullptr>
auto map_n(const F& f, const Ts&... t) {
    return cons(
        f(car(t)...),
        map_n(f, cdr(t)...)
        );
}

template<typename F, typename... Ts,
    std::enable_if_t<all_empty<Ts...>::value, int*> = nullptr>
auto map_n(const F& , const Ts&... t) {
    return std::make_tuple(t...);
}
```

Note that `tuple` isn't really the best way to do `cons`/`car`/`cdr` in C++ - it's not very `cdr`-able. More appropriate would be nested `pair`s.

You could also built up the whole `tuple` in one go with the index sequence trick. It's a little annoying here because we need to unpack two parameter packs differently, hence the extra `call` lambda. There may be a better way to do this:

```
template <size_t... Is, class F, class... Ts>
auto map_n_impl(std::index_sequence<Is...>, const F& f, const Ts&... ts) {
    auto call = [&](auto idx){
        return f(std::get<idx>(ts)...);
    };

    return std::make_tuple(
        call(std::integral_constant<size_t, Is>{})...
        );
}

template <class F, class T0, class... Ts>
auto map_n(const F& f, const T0& t0, const Ts&... ts) {
    return map_n_impl(
        std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<T0>::value>{},
        f,
        t0,
        ts...);
}
```

Comment: `s/decltype(idx)::value/idx/`.

Comment: @T.C. Didn't realize that was possible. Cool.